# How can I find some missing guard-coffeescript files?

Tags: coffeescript, bundler, guard

When setting up guard-coffeescript for a project, I can't seem to get guard to init the Guardfile. It appears to be missing some files. This is a fresh ruby install, and I haven't consciously deleted any of the mentioned files...

Anyways, I can reproduce the problem by creating a new directory with a Gemfile in it like so:

```
group :development do
  gem 'guard'
  gem 'guard-coffeescript'
end
```

Running `bundle install` succeeds without issues, but then when I run `bundle exec guard init` I get this error:

```
20:50:27 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/coffeescript' or '~/.guard/templates/coffeescript' or find class Guard::Coffeescript
20:50:27 - ERROR - Error is: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/jwashton/.guard/templates/coffeescript
```

I checked, and I don't appear to have `~/.guard`. I assume that `guard/coffeescript` would be local, and since we just created the current directory, of course that is missing. I don't know where Guard::Coffeescript would be defined.

I have used and enjoyed other guard plugins for other projects on the same machine.

- Using guard 2.12.0
- Using guard-coffeescript 1.4.0
- Using Ruby 2.1.2

*update* The problem doens't appear to be just with initializing the Guardfile. If I do so manually,  starting Guard presents me with the following:

```
22:21:33 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/coffeescript' or find class Guard::Coffeescript
22:21:33 - ERROR - Error is: cannot load such file -- guard/guard
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the details for why this fixed the problem, but the problem is resolved after these four steps:

1. Add a source line to the Gemfile. (probably `source 'https://rubygems.org'`)
2. Add a Javascript runtime. (I just used `gem 'therubyracer'`)
3. Remove the Gemfile.lock
4. Run `bundle install`

At that point, `guard init` succeeded without problems. I hope this helps somebody! I'm still not sure what went wrong...